# Failed to convert command line arguments array to symbols parameters

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, command-line-arguments, symbols

in the following script (For Ruby >= 1.9) I'm just trying to print strings to the screen versus the symbol given in the command line.

Here is my attempt (SymbolsFromArgv.rb)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def switch_sybol(symbol)
    case symbol
        when :add
            "Addition !"
        when :mul
            "Multiplication !"
        else
            "Unkown symbol #{symbol} !"
    end
end

puts switch_sybol( :add )
puts switch_sybol( :mul )
puts switch_sybol( *(ARGV.collect {|elem| elem.to_sym}) )
```

But, when I launch with :

```
$ ./SymbolsFromArgv.rb :mul
```

I get the following result :

```
Addition !
Multiplication !
Unkown symbol :mul !
```

So, why I didn't get "Multiplication !" for the last result ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`":mul".to_sym` is not `:mul`

```
":mul".to_sym
=> :":mul"
```

You need to pass just `mul`

Answer (score 1):

Shell arguments are interpreted as strings. So you should `$ ./SymbolsFromArgv.rb mul`, otherwise it will be the same as doing

```
":mul".to_sym
=> :":mul"
```